# Logging handlers not working without basicConfig

Tags: python, logging, java.util.logging

I have a Flask web application and Python Logging configuration is done via [dictConfig](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) on application startup. A handler for writing certain logs to database is attached to logger 'test.module' Logs made to that logger are written to database only if `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` is also called at application startup. Otherwise no logs are written to database. I know that basicConfig just attaches a streamHandler to root logger. I think this should be irrelevant because I don't want anything to be done by root logger. Why is this not working without basicConfig?

I added how I initiate the loggers and my configuration below.

```
class DbHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, level=logging.NOTSET):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level)

    def emit(self, record):
        record.message = self.format(record)
        log = DbModel()
        log.message = record.message
        log.save()


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'db_log': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'test.handlers.DbHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'test.important_module': {
            'handlers': [
                'db_log'
            ],
    },
}

# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) # Doesnt work without this
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

logger = logging.getLogger('test.important_module')
logger.info('Making a test')
```

Comment: Can you the code you are using to setup the logger and how that relates to the code doing the actual logging? What you have provided so far is somewhat vague...

Comment: @isedev I added it now

Comment: Just from a usability perspective, I'd rethink having the handler modify `record.message` as a side-effect.  Just set `log.message = self.format(record)` directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not setting the level for the 'test.important_module' logger itself (you only set the level for the handler).

You can do it like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('test.important_module')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Or like this:

```
'loggers': {
    'test.important_module': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',         # <<< HERE
        'handlers': [
            'db_log'
        ],
},
```

Comment: Oh thanks. Just curious, why did basicConfig had the side effect of making it work? Does it set level for all loggers?

Comment: As I understood when I called logger.info on 'test.important_module', record didn't make it to db_log handler because logger didn't have a level. After calling basicConfig, root gets the DEBUG level. So now when I call logger.info on 'test.important_module' logger still doesn't have a level so record still shouldn't make it to db_log handler. Later the record is propagated to root and I see it printed on console. But this doesn't explain why the record got recorded on the database after root gets a level. Am i wrong?

Comment: doh, sorry... my bad, dunno what I was thinking. I meant to say that test.important_module had a level of NOTSET so would inherit from root logger.